# Regex doesn't get all occurrences, but only gets the last one

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex: `(?:cassy\.jobs \((?:([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)?) [a-z]+(?:, )?)+(?:PRIMARY KEY \(([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)?)\)\))?)`

And the folowing string:

```
CREATE TABLE cassy.jobs (job_id int, job_description text, maximum_salary double, minimum_salary double, PRIMARY KEY (job_id)) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0 AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01 AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' } AND comment = '' AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 } AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' } AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE' AND min_index_interval = 128 AND max_index_interval = 2048 AND crc_check_chance = 1.0 AND cdc = false;, CREATE TABLE cassy.employees (employee_id int, email_add text, frst_name text, hire_date date, job_id int, last_name text, salary double, PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0 AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01 AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' } AND comment = '' AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 } AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' } AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE' AND min_index_interval = 128 AND max_index_interval = 2048 AND crc_check_chance = 1.0 AND cdc = false;]
```

I want to capture the column names and primary key (if exists) for a given table but I only get the last occurrence of the first capture group and the primary key.

I have read about "Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group" but the solution doesn't seem to work. I couldn't find an answer after several hours of searching.

What I get:

```
group #1: minimum_salary
group #2: job_id
```

What the result should be:

```
group #1: job_id
group #2: job_description
group #3: maximum_salary
group #4: minimum_salary
group #5: job_id
```

EDIT: Added java tag, if this is not possible with regex alone, java code can be used.

Comment: Your capturing group is contained in a repeated structure? The group will only contain what was captured last, that's the expected behaviour. There are usual two ways to workaround, either capturing the whole thing and splitting it in a next step or changing your pattern to make use of `\G`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with regex, but takes 2 to get the end result. Using an abbreviation of your regex, in addition to a second regex, we can pull out the column names from this specific table:

```
regex1 = /(?:cassy\.jobs \(.*?\))/
regex2 = /(?:\s*([a-z_]+) [a-z]+|PRIMARY KEY\s\((.*?)\))/gm
```

Not the most knowledgable in Java, but in JS, this is how I would do it:

```js
let regex1 = /(?:cassy\.jobs \(.*?\))/,
  regex2 = /(?:\s*([a-z_]+) [a-z]+|PRIMARY KEY\s\((.*?)\))/gm,
  string = "CREATE TABLE cassy.jobs (job_id int, job_description text, maximum_salary double, minimum_salary double, PRIMARY KEY (job_id)) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0 AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01 AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' } AND comment = '' AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 } AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' } AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE' AND min_index_interval = 128 AND max_index_interval = 2048 AND crc_check_chance = 1.0 AND cdc = false;, CREATE TABLE cassy.employees (employee_id int, email_add text, frst_name text, hire_date date, job_id int, last_name text, salary double, PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0 AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01 AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' } AND comment = '' AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 } AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' } AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE' AND min_index_interval = 128 AND max_index_interval = 2048 AND crc_check_chance = 1.0 AND cdc = false;]",
  createTable = regex1.exec(string),
  columnNames = [];

// Put all capture group matches into the columnNames array
while ((m = regex2.exec(createTable)) !== null) {
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    if (match !== undefined && groupIndex !== 0) {
      columnNames.push(match)
    }
  });
}

console.log(columnNames)
```